# Word request: Sensory words

Tags: meaning, synonyms, vocabulary

I'm trying to gather a list of appropriate words that relate in analogous ways for 5 classical senses. Right now I think I've got:

Eye/sight:ocular:optic:visual
Ear/hearing:otic:aural:auditory
Nose/smell:nasal:rhinal:olfactory
Mouth/taste:oral:?:gustatory

(but I welcome corrections on any of these)

But skin/hands is tricky. I think dermal is in there (but maybe cutaneous is better?) . I'm not sure if tactile or haptic is more appropriate. And I don't begin to have a guess as to what the other 2 words would be.

Any help on any of these would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the different categories for each sense?

Comment: haptic is for iPhones. [she smiled]

Comment: The rough breakdown I'm using up there is: of or relating to [sense organ] : of or relating to [sense organ] or [sense] : of or relating to [sense]

Comment: Tangential: the missing word in your 4th series may be "buccal" according to definition 2 listed here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buccal

Comment: sensory, not sensatory.

Comment: Thanks @Lambie no idea how/why I screwed that up

Comment: No worries. It happens to the best of us. :)

Answer (score 5):

One word I'd certainly suggest is **tactile**, whose prototypical meaning is:

> *tactile* [adjective]:
>
> of or connected with the sense of touch.

[[ODE courtesy of Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=tactile+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=tactile+mea&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqCggAEAAYsQMYgAQyCggAEAAYsQMYgAQyBggBEEUYOTIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDIHCAYQABiABDIHCAcQABiABDIHCAgQABiABDIHCAkQABiABKgCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

(There are related subsenses.)

An example of this usage is:

> - It had also been reported, although merely in passing, that they had lost all tactile sensations when they became ill.

[[Liljencrantz & Olausson; Frontiers](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fnbeh.2014.00037/full)]